# What is the best way to use gorm in multithreaded application?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have an application that opens a lot routines. Lets say 2000 routines. Each routine needs access to DB, or at least needs update/select data from DB.

My current approach is the following:

Routine gets `*gorm.DB` with `db.GetConnection()`, this is the code of this function:

```
func GetConnection() *gorm.DB {
    DBConfig := config.GetConfig().DB
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", DBConfig.DBUser+":"+DBConfig.DBPassword+"@/"+DBConfig.DBName+"?charset=utf8mb4")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return db
}
```

then routines calls another function from some storage package and passes `*gorm.DB` to function and closes the connection, it looks like that:

```
dbConnection := db.GetConnection()
postStorage.UpdateSomething(dbConnection)
db.CloseConnection(dbConnection)
```

The above is only example, the main idea is that each routine opens new connection and I don't like it. Because it may overload the DB. In result I got the next MySQL error:

```
[mysql] 2020/07/16 19:34:26 packets.go:37: read tcp 127.0.0.1:44170->127.0.0.1:3306: read: connection reset by peer
```

The question is about good pattern how to use `gorm` package in multiroutines application ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*gorm.DB` is multi thread safe, and you could use one `*gorm.DB` in multi routines. You could init it once and get it whenever you want. Demo:

```
package db

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    DBConfig := config.GetConfig().DB
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", DBConfig.DBUser+":"+DBConfig.DBPassword+"@/"+DBConfig.DBName+"?charset=utf8mb4")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func GetConnection() *gorm.DB {
    return db;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I init it one time when application started, how can I keep it alive ? Because application is always running. And I think after sometime without queries mysql will close connection and then when application will make query - I will get error.. Please clarify this moment

Comment: @Mikael It depends on the driver you import and `database/sql`. For example, [github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) is a MySQL-Driver for Go's `database/sql`. Default, it will help you maintain a connection pool, do something like keeping the connection alive, scaling under load (when many goroutines are actively using the database), and shrinking when quiescent. So you may not need to worry about that.

Comment: thanks, very useful! Sorry, one more question, do I need to close connection ?
I tried `*gorm.DB.Close()`, but then other routines say that connection is closed.

Comment: @Mikael About the last question in comment, if you don't, and in case your application terminated unexpectedly (e.g killed), then it depends on the database server how long a connection can be idle before closed, you may configure your database server on that behavior.